# Specify class type in function annotations

Tags: python

So I have a function that takes a class as a parameter (not a class instance!).

How can I specify this in the function annotation

What I mean is:

```
def add(a: int, b: int):
```

But I can't do this:

```
def my_func(cls: class):
```

Since class is a reserved word for class definition. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cls: type`.

Just like every integer is an instance of `int`, every class is an instance of `type`.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
>>> 
>>> isinstance(Foo, type)
>>> True
>>> isinstance(Foo(), type)
>>> False
```

You can also use `Type` from the `typing` module, which, as per the docs, is

> A special construct usable to annotate class objects.

Using `typing.Type` is more flexible than `cls:type`.

For example, if you wanted to hint that the argument can be any class object, you simply use `cls:Type`.

If the argument should be any class object that is a subclass of the class `Foo` (or `Foo` itself), you can write `cls: Type[Foo]`.

[Read the docs for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

Responding to the comments:

> it's like in your example. Class object is an instance of type, but class instance isn't. So that's why it complains: going `func(Person)` is alright but `func(Person('Steve', 22))` is not.

In the second case, you are doing what you explicitly said you don't want to do: pass an *instance* of `Person`, not the class `Person`. So your IDE rightfully complains if you annotated `type` or `Type`.

Comment: well I've thought of it, I just don't like the fact that PyCharm says 'expected type 'type' got 'class' instead

Comment: @Desiigner does it complain with `from typing import Type` and then `cls:Type`?

Comment: If you're going to annotate as a type of `type` though - you might as well not bother... `int`/`list`/`dict` are all true for `isinstance(obj, type)`...

Comment: @JonClements right, but not *instances* of `int`/`list`/`dict` (as you know). I think OP just wants to make sure that the argument is a class. `isinstance(int(), type)` -> `False`.

Comment: @timgeb I guess my whole idea is weird. It's fine if I say my_function(Foo) but then I'm not able to set any attributes to this class because it becomes my_function(Foo(attrs)). Though your answer is the right one.

Comment: @timgeb do you think it's a bad idea to pass a class to a function definition?

Comment: @Desiigner well we don't have much context in your question to work with, but could you please answer my question whether Pycharm still complains if you use `Type` from the `typing` module?

Comment: @timgeb it does since I'm passing a class with attributes.

Comment: @Desiigner I don't see why the class having attributes would be a problem. *Every* class has attributes (i.e. a non-empty class level `__dict__`). Anyway, I blame everything on Pycharm, the annotation is correct.

Comment: @timgeb it's like in your example. Class object is an instance of type, but class instance isn't. So that's why it complains: going func(Person) is alright but func(Person('Steve', 22)) is not.

Comment: @Desiigner yes, but in your question you say that you don't want to pass an instance. `Person('Steve', 22)` is an instance so your IDE *should* complain if you annotated `type`.

Comment: @Desiigner also, if you still have trouble because your actual problem is not quite what you asked about, I encourage you to open a new question and provide a little bit more context about what you are trying to achieve.